# Animation issue in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's what I have so far based for an alarm view animation that I'm working on

```
struct AlarmView: View {
    @State var alarmSet = false
    @State var animateBell = false
    @State var alarmText = "Remind Me"
    @State var shouldAnimate = false
    @State private var bellID: UUID = UUID()
    @State private var timeSinceLastTap = Date.now
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // animate only if there is some time elapsed between taps
                    let duration = min(0.3, abs(timeSinceLastTap.timeIntervalSinceNow))
                    shouldAnimate = duration > 0.2
                    alarmText = !alarmSet ? "Reminder Set" : "Remind Me"

                    if shouldAnimate {
                        if alarmSet == true { // turn OFF alarm
                            alarmSet.toggle()
                        } else { // animate the bell, then turn ON alarm
                            animateBell.toggle()
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                alarmSet.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // to cancel animation
                        bellID = UUID()
                        alarmSet.toggle()
                    }
                    timeSinceLastTap = Date.now
                    
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            if alarmSet {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .font(.system(size: 150))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 150))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .id(bellID)
                                    .keyframeAnimator(initialValue: Angle.zero, trigger: animateBell) { content, value in
                                        content.rotationEffect(value, anchor: .top)
                                    } keyframes: { _ in
                                        KeyframeTrack {
                                            let spring = Spring(mass: 0.5, stiffness: 170, damping: 2.5)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.05, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.zero, duration: 0.05, spring: spring, startVelocity: Angle.zero)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        Text(alarmText)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                })
                .buttonStyle(NoAnimationStyle())
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct NoAnimationStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture(perform: configuration.trigger)
    }
}
```

This works well for the most part except for the following scenario. When tapping the button while in its default state (with the bell showing and text saying "Remind me"), if I tap again while the bell is animating/wiggling it momentarily shows the checkmark before showing the bell again.

However the text continues to say "Reminder Set" instead of defaulting to "Remind Me". The effect I'm trying to replicate is the reminder animation in the Netflix app in their 'New & Hot' screen. From what I checked, the Netflix animation is buggy on iOS where quick taps cause it to animate horribly even after the taps have ended. On Android however, the animation is perfect wherein if user taps twice quickly, just the text changes while the icon stays unchanged and does not switch at all between quick taps.

In my case ideally I'd like for the bell animation to cancel even if mid animation & not show the checkmark at all and for the text to be set appropriately. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to stop the animation. SwiftUI already does that out of the box.

You really only need two states

```
@State var alarmSet = false
@State var animateBell = false
@State var showCheckmark = false
```

These control the text in the button, the animation, and the checkmark respectively.

And the button's logic can be as simple as:

```
if alarmSet {
    alarmSet = false
    showCheckmark = false
} else {
    animateBell.toggle()
    alarmSet = true
    withAnimation(.default.delay(0.5)) {
        showCheckmark = true
    }
}
```

When the alarm is not set, `animateBell.toggle()` starts the animation (and it's fine to start the animation multiple times - SwiftUI can correctly handle that), then immediately we update the text, then with a 0.5 second delay, we show the checkmark.

When the alarm is set, we simply want to update the text and remove the checkmark.

I think your mistake is that you are `toggle`ing things unnecessarily, causing them to have incorrect values.

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var alarmSet = false
    @State var animateBell = false
    @State var showCheckmark = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    if alarmSet {
                        alarmSet = false
                        showCheckmark = false
                    } else {
                        animateBell.toggle()
                        alarmSet = true
                        withAnimation(.default.delay(0.5)) {
                            showCheckmark = true
                        }
                    }
                    
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            if showCheckmark {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .font(.system(size: 150))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 150))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .keyframeAnimator(initialValue: Angle.zero, trigger: animateBell) { content, value in
                                        content.rotationEffect(value, anchor: .top)
                                    } keyframes: { _ in
                                        KeyframeTrack {
                                            let spring = Spring(mass: 0.5, stiffness: 170, damping: 2.5)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.05, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
                                            SpringKeyframe(Angle.zero, duration: 0.05, spring: spring, startVelocity: Angle.zero)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        Text(alarmSet ? "Reminder Set" : "Remind Me")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a go, unfortunately it's different from what I'm trying to create. Given the initial state (1.) when the button is tapped, the text should change immediately to Reminder Set and the bell should start to animate. After bell animation completes should the checkmark display. (2.) Now if you tap the button, the text should change immediately to Remind Me and the bell should show without animation. (3.) Now between step #1 & step #2, if you tap the button while the bell is animating, the bell should show without animation and the text should change to Remind Me.

Comment: [Here's a gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HAaSquavmn3Fvva0O-lttrcnricvpNVS/view?usp=sharing). Towards the end, though it may not look like it but im tapping very quickly so you may notice the text change but not the icon.

Comment: @batman Okay. Updated the answer.

Comment: This works great, just one minor thing. Now the bell stays as is between taps but the checkmark briefly shows the bell when tapped quickly.

Comment: @batman I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.0 Simulator. Isn't "the bell stays as is between taps but the checkmark briefly shows the bell when tapped quickly" a contradiction? Does the bell stays as is or does the checkmark appear? These are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify it. So given any state i.e. bell or checkmark, if tapped quickly twice they stay as is. I know I mentioned it only for the bell but it'd be great if the same could be applied for the checkmark as well.

Comment: @batman What you are saying doesn't quite make sense. Unlike the transition from bell to checkmark, the transition from checkmark to bell is *instantaneous*. You even said that in step 2 of your first comment. There is no such thing as "tapped the checkmark too quickly" (which I assume means tapping again during the animation), because there is no animation. You tap the checkmark, it becomes a bell instantly, and you tap the bell. Do you want the transition from checkmark to bell to also take some time?

Comment: What im trying to get at is, regardless of which icon shows if you tap it twice quickly, regardless of any animation occurring or not; the same icon should remain since essentially you are resetting back to that state when tapping twice. The code you provided as is works well in the case when the bell shows i.e. if I tap twice quickly it doesnt show the checkmark in between the taps. The same does not happen in the case of the checkmark. If the checkmark is showing & if you tap twice quickly; the bell shows momentarily before showing the checkmark again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256191/discussion-between-sweeper-and-batman).